# WPF - Adding ScatterViewItem.Content to a StackPanel as UIElement

Tags: wpf, stackpanel, uielement, scatterview

I'm attempting to make a application where you can drag ScatterViewItems next to each other, and the items will dock together, so that you can move them around as a single item.

Right now I'm trying to create a `StackPanel` and add the content of the two ScatterViewItems being docked to it, but am not sure how to convert the SVI's content property to a `UIElement` in any meaningful way. Has anyone tried to do something similar, or have any ideas on how to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the ScatterPuzzle example in the Surface SDK.  It shows precisely how to accomplish this scenario of snapping items together

Comment: I was looking at that, but didn't see anywhere I could download the example. I'll go back and look at it again.

Comment: @Geogre - it's part of the SDK itself